# Selenium RC verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent(“string”))

Tags: selenium

I have a few questions regarding the Selenium RC ->VerifyTextPresent 
By example: `(verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent()));`

I found an spelling error in the text on the page when running the test from the Selenium IDE, but the error was not caught when running the test via Selenium RC/JUnit.

I understand that I need to add the method: `checkForVerificationErrors();` to java code to have the same result as in IDE.

For example this code/line (verification)->
IDE:

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyTextPresent</td>
    <td>Search results: 1 - 30 of 50</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Selenium RC/JUnit: `verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Search results: 1 - 30 of 50"));`

After I added `checkForVerificationErrors();` method, Selenium RC it works as IDE.

Here is the complete code:

```
package com.example.tests;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Dice_Search extends SeleneseTestCase {
    private Selenium selenium;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.dice.com/");
        selenium.setSpeed("2000");
        selenium.start();
        selenium.windowMaximize();
        selenium.windowFocus();
    }

    @Test
    public void testDice_Search() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.type("id=FREE_TEXT", "selenium");
        selenium.type("id=zipCodeCity", "Los Angeles, CA");
        selenium.click("id=searchSubmit");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Search results: 1 - 30 of 50"));
        verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Create Search Agent Matching These Results"));
        verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("selenium"));
        verifyEquals("selenium", selenium.getText("css=div.undoLabel"));
        checkForVerificationErrors();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        selenium.stop();
    }
}
```

Now the questions:

1. How is much better to add checkForVerificationErrors(); after each  (verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent())); line or can be added at the end of the test like in the above code?
2. How can I know at what line in Selenium RC/JUnit the test is failed? In Selenium IDE in the Log window it's show the line, also the command is marked with red. In JUnit only show a Failure Trace, not the line which produced the test error.

See the below screenshots:
[image: IDE]

[image: JUnit]

Thank you!
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

i'm not very good with RC, but here is what i'm thinking of:
1. I don't understand why are you using verifyTextPresent - better solution is find exact element you need and check text within element? (Something like: verifyTrue(element.getText().equals("text"))
2. Read stack trace information, if you are using Eclipse IDE you could click links within Console tab