# How to use "isTrue" method of "Text" class?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to use "isTrue" method of text class

Here is the "Text" class detail

```
http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html
```

// Code i have written

```
public void researchSelenium(){

    driver.get(baseUrl);

    ConditionRunner.Context cont = new Research();
    Text obj = new Text("Why implement a customer referral program?");
    System.out.println(obj.isTrue(cont));

    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
```

I dont know what to do here

```
ConditionRunner.Context cont = new Research(); //After "new" what should i write?
```

object of ConditionRunner.Context will pass to "isTrue" method

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. What are you intending to do? What does the `Research` class do? What should `obj.isTrue` do? I am assuming you are trying to get the title of something on a page, and then verify what that is?

Comment: Have to agree this code doesn't make sense to me either.

Comment: it check for specified text is present on page or not
See the constructor Text
Text obj = new Text("Why implement a customer referral program?");

Comment: Possible Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221406/selenium-rc-verifytrueselenium-istextpresentstring ?

Comment: That's now what the `isTrue` method is for; it's there so you can wait for a condition to be true. If you want to check whether specified text is present on the page or not, I recommend you look into [Junit Asserts](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html#usingjunit_asserts).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a few presumptions here:

- `driver` is a selenium web driver instance
- You are trying to find if a text field is present in your web page
- You know what the text is, but not its xpath (or at least do not care "where" it is).

In this case, you just have a minor syntaxical error

```
public void researchSelenium()
{
    driver.get(baseUrl);

    //Not sure what this is doing.
    ConditionRunner.Context cont = new Research();

    //Small chgange here
    string obj = "Why implement a customer referral program?";
    System.out.println(driver.isTextPresent(obj));

    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
}
```

NB. the above is "free coded" and I've not tested/complied it. Feel free to edit if there's a minor problem.

APPEND:

Personally I'd use NUnit to handle tests, so in that case I'd use:

`Assert.isTrue(driver.isTextPresent(obj));`

To test if that text was actually present, but how you're running your tests is not something that's stated in your question.